# how to return the element tree instance

Tags: python, elementtree

I want to generate a xml file. I have written a xml_generator method. When /xxx url hits i call this generator function. how should i return this Because returning instance of generator function creates an error.

Comment: -1 for posting a bad question __and then__ downvoting somebody that tried to answer it.

Comment: the question is vague. That makes it bad. Downvote people all you want, just do it for the right reasons.

Comment: -1.  I can't make heads or tails what this is about.  Post some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you meant you're returning a function, it will be erroneous when you're actually trying to return the results of the function. I.e.: `my_function` instead of `my_function()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to help... Here is another idea: A function doesn't have instances, but if you meant you're returning a function, it will be erroneous when you're actually trying to return the results of the function. I.e.: my_function() instead of my_function. Maybe you just forgot ()? Please don't down-vote me again if this has not solved your problem. We need some more information, maybe a bit of source code, to understand your question.

Comment: functions are first class objects? how does returning a function from a function cause an error? You could pass a function around and do quite a bit to it (attribute assignments for example) without getting an error.